# web2py - do I need another server for a real time application?

Tags: websocket, tornado, web2py

In the web2py examples there is a websocket example which uses tornado here:

`gluon/contrib/websocket_messaging.py` and this requires another server to be started namely `tornado`. My questions is, do I need another server? Should I only have one server to handle both the websocket stuff and the normal http requests?

Also, it seems tornado is the server of choice for the 2nd server, could that be something different?

I'm a bit of a newbie to websockets (and webapp development) so any comments/links that would help me better understand this would be appreciated.

Comment: As the Web Server service if you want to use (<1 MS response time ).
Service it would be reasonable to do with the server socket. If you scan the query type, the less you'll get if you make it so quick response. A large part of the burden of the process you will need to make the user side.

Comment: sorry I don't understand your reply can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python WSGI based frameworks such as web2py are typically served via threaded web servers. A typical HTTP request occupies one of the server threads only very briefly in order to receive the incoming request and deliver the response, then freeing the thread to serve another incoming request.

Websockets (and long polling), on the other hand, require a long-lived connection between the client (i.e., browser) and the web server. A websocket connection will therefore occupy a thread indefinitely, so you can only have as many connections as you have threads, thus limiting the application to a relatively small number of concurrent users.

In order to enable many simultaneous websocket connections, it is therefore best to serve websockets via a server that features non-blocking network I/O, such as Tornado. For more details, see http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html.

Another option is to use [Gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) with [monkey patching](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#monkey-patching), which can be used in the context of a WSGI application as described [here](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html). Keep in mind, though, that any libraries you use that involve network I/O (such as database drivers) must be compatible with this approach (either via monkey patching or code explicitly designed for coroutines).

If realtime/server-push functionality is a major aspect of your application, and especially if you are new to web development, you might instead consider a framework built for this specific use case, such as [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/).

Comment: ok so just to be clear, if I stick with web2py I will have the web2py server listening on all (?) ports and tornado will listen only on a specific port which I use for real-time communication purposes correct?

Comment: Yes, though the web2py server would not be listening on all ports, but on a specific port (typically port 80).